# How can i move next line in VHDL write & writeline function

Tags: vhdl

I try to write VHDL simulation result at txt file.

I can write some data.

But i like to stack these data by row order. That is, there is new line between saved data.

I exptected writeline function to move newline. But it isn`t.

```
TEXT_OUT : process (I_CLK,I_RST)
file    file_RESULTS    : text open write_mode is "output_result.txt";     
variable    v_OLINE        : line;
 begin 
    if (I_RST = '1') then
          null;           
    elsif (rising_edge(I_CLK)) then
       if (I_BRAM_ENA = '1') then
         hwrite(v_OLINE, O_ADDRB, left, 5);      
         writeline(file_RESULTS, v_OLINE);          
             report "Save the output address!";            
       end if;       
    end if;            
 end process;
```

if O_ADDRB have sequentially 0000, 0001, 0002, as time gone.

Then output_result.txt have data like below

0000

0001

0002

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a clear problem statement. If you're simply trying to append a new line character then after `hwrite(v_OLINE, O_ADDRB, left, 5);` insert a new statement `write (v_OLINE, LF);` before `writeline(file_RESULTS, v_OLINE);`.

Comment: writeline writes the text in v_OLINE to the text file then appends a \n to the end of it. If you want columns of data, you have to generate the whole line before writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print in new line then probably I can't help you unless you have to do it all in one go, without having to close the file and open again (in which case you can follow as mentioned in comments by user1155120.
But if it is only for debugging purposes, then use this code to print in console:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use std.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;

procedure writeproc(sig: in std_logic_vector; s : string) is
    variable li : line;
    variable str : string(1 to sig'length);
    file f_in : text; -- open read_mode is "output";
    file f_out : text; -- open write_mode is "output";
begin
    file_open(f_out, "output", write_mode);
    write(li, std_logic_vector(sig));
    write(li, lf);  writeline(f_out, li);
    file_close(f_out);
    file_open(f_in, "output", read_mode);
    readline(f_in, li);
    read(li, str);
    file_close(f_in);
    report "read " & s & str;
end procedure writeproc;
```